# Is "recaler" commonly used as an informal equivalent of "recalculer" in conversation?

Tags: vocabulaire

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/pB-7dTUJUB8?t=144) on YouTube. I think he said:

> Il a donc fallu que je **recale** chaque groupe de notes pour avoir quelque chose qui ressemble à un chat mais qui soit quand même musical ou au moins un petit peu.

I'm quite sure that he said "recale", but the only usage of the verb "recaler" that I know of is in the sense of "fail" which does not apply to this context. Given the context, I wonder if it is a shortened form of "recalculer", though I cannot seem to find any dictionary entry for this.

Is "recaler" commonly used in conversation as an equivalent of "recalculer"? Or have I heard wrong, and is it actually some other word?

Comment: Could it be « [recalque](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/calquer) » ?

Answer (score 1):

The verb [*recaler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/recaler) means readjust here, not that other [*recaler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/recaler/1). It is also unrelated to *recalculer*.

*Recaler* means *caler* again, i.e. adjust something with the help of a *cale*: a wedge (German *Keil*).

The idea is to draw a cat on a "read sheet music" (midi clips), possibly with [this software](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ableton_Live), then slightly readjust (i.e. *recaler*) the notes to reach an acceptable piece of music.

Comment: By the way, I wonder if it isn't better to say "*mais/et qui **en même temps** soit musical*" rather than "***quand même***", given the context?

Comment: Not better, but possible. With *quand même*, it is assumed a cat drawing is not naturally "musical" while with *en même temps* the negative correlation is less stressed. That's "nevertheless/still" vs "at the same time".

Comment: caler les notes, décaler les notes, et les re-caler: on le voit ici: https://books.google.com/books?id=nOViybYFzpoC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=re-caler+les+notes+:.fr&source=bl&ots=WNZOE4lxrR&sig=DNbTldhVkPiv418LuBxBrwbAgu8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi96urNmavYAhVDct8KHbz-ARcQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=re-caler%20les%20notes%20%3A.fr&f=false It's not normal conversation, it is used in music.

Comment: Pinterest a plein de chats avec ou sur des partitions de musique.

Comment: @Lambie *Recaler* can be used in several "normal conversation" contexts, not just music.

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'ai jamais dit le contraire. Il me semble, néanmoins, qu'ici le dessin pourrait être sur une partition, et donc un peu spéciale. J'éspère qu'on ne va  pas me "recaler" (encore), cela fait bien des années que l'école pour moi, c'est finie. Après tout le brouhaha. Il me semble qu'indépendamment de ce que je dis, on pourrait imaginer que je sais ce que recaler veut dire, dans plusieures contextes. Et il me semblait intéressant de faire remarquer le contexte musicale. Ai-je tort? Ou faut-il rester coi?

Comment: @Lambie Pas de problème. J'étais étonné du *not normal conversation* qui pouvait laisser penser que *recaler* n'était pas un verbe courant en français. Le contexte musical ne fait bien sûr aucun doute ici.

Comment: @jlliagre   Et bien dans le texte en question, ce n'est  pas "normal conversation", n'est-ce pas? Et puis, ce n'est pas non plus un synonyme de recalculer.....par contre, je vous pose la question: faut-il un tiret ou pas? :) [tutoyer, c'est OK ou pas?]

Comment: @Lambie Sur FSE, le tutoiement est [encouragé](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie). Je n'ai bien sûr aucun problème à être tutoyé/tutoyer ici. *Recaler* ne faisant pas partie d'un jargon particulier mais étant compris par tout francophone, comme dérivé de *caler*, c'est pour moi un verbe "normal". Il n'y a pas de tiret à *recaler*.